# Expand a matrix of counts

Tags: r

Say I have this matrix:

```
set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:3, 25, TRUE), ncol = 5)
rownames(mat) <- month.abb[1:5]
colnames(mat) <- state.name[1:5]

mat

##     Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California
## Jan       2      0       2        1          3
## Feb       1      1       2        0          2
## Mar       1      1       0        1          3
## Apr       2      2       2        1          1
## May       0      1       1        3          1
```

I am looking for an efficient (non-base solutions welcome) way to expand each observation/row n times (n dictated by the max in that row) and fill in with either 1 or 0 as seen below (I'm not sure if this techniques has a name but if anyone has comments on this expansion I'd love to know what it's called; makes googling easier).

```
##     Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California
## Jan       1      0       1        1          1
## Jan       1      0       1        0          1
## Jan       0      0       0        0          1
## Feb       1      1       1        0          1
## Feb       0      0       1        0          1
## Mar       1      1       0        1          1
## Mar       0      0       0        0          1
## Mar       0      0       0        0          1
## Apr       1      1       1        1          1
## Apr       1      1       1        0          0
## May       0      1       1        1          1
## May       0      0       0        1          0
## May       0      0       0        1          0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, also, ...somehow seems valid:

```
maxs = mat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), max.col(mat, "first"))]
(mat[rep(seq_len(nrow(mat)), maxs), ] >= sequence(maxs)) + 0L
#    Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California
#Jan       1      0       1        1          1
#Jan       1      0       1        0          1
#Jan       0      0       0        0          1
#Feb       1      1       1        0          1
#Feb       0      0       1        0          1
#Mar       1      1       0        1          1
#Mar       0      0       0        0          1
#Mar       0      0       0        0          1
#Apr       1      1       1        1          1
#Apr       1      1       1        0          0
#May       0      1       1        1          1
#May       0      0       0        1          0
#May       0      0       0        1          0
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what this expansion is called but here's one way to do it:

```
expand.row <- function(x) {
  out <- matrix(rep(rep(1:0, times=length(x)), c(rbind(x,max(x)-x))), ncol=length(x))
  colnames(out) <- names(x)
  return(out)
}

mat2 <- do.call(rbind,apply(mat,1,expand.row))
rownames(mat2) <- rep(rownames(mat), apply(mat, 1, max))

##     Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California
## Jan       1      0       1        1          1
## Jan       1      0       1        0          1
## Jan       0      0       0        0          1
## Feb       1      1       1        0          1
## Feb       0      0       1        0          1
## Mar       1      1       0        1          1
## Mar       0      0       0        0          1
## Mar       0      0       0        0          1
## Apr       1      1       1        1          1
## Apr       1      1       1        0          0
## May       0      1       1        1          1
## May       0      0       0        1          0
## May       0      0       0        1          0
```

Hopefully, someone will come along and provide an obvious function from a well-known package, but maybe this will get you by until then.

Comment: Added rownames fix; feel free to roll back.

Comment: @TylerRinker Ugh! You beat me to it, haha! Literally the exact same approach I had in mind. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker  Looks good.  I was hoping to be able to get the row names without creating another object, but I couldn't think how.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyr option:

```
library(dplyr)

# Expand the number of rows
mat.exp = mat[rep(rownames(mat), apply(mat, 1, max)),]

# Get the 1s and 0s right
mat.exp = mat.exp %>% as.data.frame %>% add_rownames %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(c(rep(1,.[1]), rep(0,n() - .[1]))))

# Convert back to matrix and add back rownames
mat.exp = as.matrix(mat.exp[,-1])
rownames(mat.exp) = rep(rownames(mat), apply(mat, 1, max))

mat.exp

        Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California
    Jan       1      0       1        1          1
    Jan       1      0       1        0          1
    Jan       0      0       0        0          1
    Feb       1      1       1        0          1
    Feb       0      0       1        0          1
    Mar       1      1       0        1          1
    Mar       0      0       0        0          1
    Mar       0      0       0        0          1
    Apr       1      1       1        1          1
    Apr       1      1       1        0          0
    May       0      1       1        1          1
    May       0      0       0        1          0
    May       0      0       0        1          0
```